# MongoDB not getting connected to EC2 server

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

```
 mongo mongodb+srv://root:<password>@cluster0-5etkj.mongodb.net:27017/cretanium?retryWrites=true
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
connecting to: mongodb+srv://root:<password>@cluster0-5etkj.mongodb.net:27017/cretanium?retryWrites=true
2020-01-08T12:14:51.648+0000 Assertion failure _setName.size() src/mongo/client/dbclientinterface.h 231
2020-01-08T12:14:51.649+0000 0x6b75c9 0x659e9f 0x636a32 0x5013b8 0x4fa7f1 0x6006fd 0x5eb869 0x7f8128226d76 0x3340f1406362 
 mongo(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x39) [0x6b75c9]
 mongo(_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc+0x21f) [0x659e9f]
 mongo(_ZN5mongo12verifyFailedEPKcS1_j+0x142) [0x636a32]
 mongo(_ZN5mongo16ConnectionStringC1ENS0_14ConnectionTypeERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES9_+0x208) [0x5013b8]
 mongo(_ZN5mongo16ConnectionString5parseERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERS6_+0x201) [0x4fa7f1]
 mongo(_ZN5mongo17mongoConsExternalEPNS_7V8ScopeERKN2v89ArgumentsE+0x11d) [0x6006fd]
 mongo(_ZN5mongo7V8Scope10v8CallbackERKN2v89ArgumentsE+0xa9) [0x5eb869]
 /usr/lib/libv8.so.3.14.5(+0x99d76) [0x7f8128226d76]
 [0x3340f1406362]
2020-01-08T12:14:51.650+0000 Error: assertion src/mongo/client/dbclientinterface.h:231 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148
exception: connect failed
```

I am trying to connect to mongo atlas using command line on EC2 Server and it is getting connected on my local machine but I cannot connect it on EC2 Server. I'm able to ping to google.com, so external connectivity is not an issue but I'm unable to connect to mongodb from ec2 command line as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `mongo` shell version 2.6.10. This version is not supported anymore.

This is an expected error when you're trying to connect to a newer server version (Atlas is currently using either 3.6, 4.0, or 4.2 as of this moment) using an old shell version (see [SERVER-16610](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-16610)).

Please upgrade your local MongoDB installation to a newer one. See [Install MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/) for an instruction for your specific OS.